# Problema com os resultados

Tags: c

Gostaria de saber, no programa eu entro com 10 valores, e o programa calcula a transformada discreta do cosseno-II, usando essa sequencia de 10 números:

```
3
5
7
9
7
5
3
5
8
9
```

Por que o primeiro valor da 30.000000 e não 61.000000??

Segue abaixo o trecho do código com a conta:

```
for(i = 0; i < N; i++)
{
    DCT = 0;

    for(j = 0; j < N; j++)
    {
        DCT += vetor[i] * cos((PI/N * (j + 0.5) )* i); //Formula da transformada discreta do cosseno
    }

    printf("%lf\n", DCT);
}
```

Comment: Se você já verificou que a fórmula está correta, será que o erro não está na inicialização de `DCT` com 0 *dentro* do primeiro `for`? Não deveria ser fora dele (antes de tudo)? Caso contrário, essa variável é reinicializada a cada iteração desse primeiro laço...

Answer (score 1):

> ```
>         DCT += vetor[i] * cos((PI/N * (j + 0.5)) * i);
> ```

A [fórmula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_cosine_transform#DCT-II) está mal implementada.

```
        DCT += vetor[j] * cos((PI/N * (j + 0.5)) * i);
        //           ^
```